# Run ffmpeg using shell_exec from a file called by AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, ffmpeg, shell-exec

Good morning,

I will do my best to phrase a "thoughtful" and "helpful" question for all regarding running FFMPEG using shell_exec from a file called by AJAX. First I will start by listing my current code.

AJAX script

```
        <script>
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }else{// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                  //Do something
              }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","video_convert.php",true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send(id=<?php echo $video_upload_result; ?>);
        </script>
```

PHP Code

```
$destination = "files/videos/";
$ffmpeg = '/ffmpeg/ffmpeg';
$videoid = mysql_clean($_GET['id']);

$sql = "SELECT file_name FROM cb_video WHERE videoid = '$videoid' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$file_old = glob('files/videos/'.$file_name.'.*');

shell_exec($ffmpeg." -i '/var/www/html/".$file_old[0]."' -ar 44100 /var/www/html/".$destination.$file_name.".flv");
```

FFMPEG is installed and working properly as I have used it elsewhere on the site and have attempted a file conversion using PuTTY. I am able to run a PHP file called by AJAX as I have done it in a separate instance on this site. The only thing I can think of is that the shell_exec isn't running properly, which I have used elsewhere, since it is in a separate file called by ajax or else it is being closed pre-maturely. I have also tested this code in a main file and it works properly until I try to call the separate file with it in it.

So, my question is can this code actually work and if so what steps should I take to get it working?

Also I would greatly appreciate it if before closing my questions I had a chance to defend or rephrase them to properly suit this boards high standards for questions if I have somehow failed it in any way.

Thank you.

Comment: So it isn't working now? And the cmd line where you pass in filename.* to convert to filename.flv works? You'll need to get the value from $row before you make the call too.

Comment: Actually I forgot that I changed that. I changed the main post to reflect the change so that the actual file name is used in the command.

Comment: If you output the cmd line (instead of 'shell_exec') and paste it into a cmd window - does it work?

Comment: Yes it works in a cmd window.

Comment: So you should be fine. Is it not working?

Comment: The code works perfectly fine when it is included in a main PHP file that the user goes to. If I put the code in a separate file that is triggered via Ajax it doesn't run the shell_exec command to trigger ffmpeg and convert a video file.

Comment: Can you run anything via shell_exec? IE is it that ffmpeg  is somehow missing / not allowed or is there a larger issue?

Comment: Check that the I'd is passed correctly by echoing the result.

Comment: ffmpeg runs fine in the main file with shell_exec. It only doesn't appear to work when I use it in a separate file called by ajax. Also the file won't return anything at all. I will test it more in January as I wont be working again until then.

Comment: There are no quotes around your string being passed here: `xmlhttp.send(id=<?php echo $video_upload_result; ?>);`, currently scanning for any other little mistakes.

Comment: I have the same problem